# Wordpress asking for username and Password on homepage

Tags: wordpress, jwt

I installed and configured the jwt-auth plugin for WordPress and configured it as it says in the documentation, i.e by editing the .htaccess file as it said.
But after that when opens my website ..Its asking for username and password. after entering, i can visit website?
How can i remove remove login popup.

Comment: Check if there `.htpasswd` file.

Comment: Got the issue. i have activated the plugin application password..After deactivation ...its starts working normal...